# DCF77 - No Signal detected

Tags: gpio, rtc, beaglebone-black

I'm using a Conrad DCF77 to get RTC on Beaglebone Black and wiring it so:

1--> GND |
2--> VCC 3,3 V |
3--> One of the gpios  (P8_11)

To read the Signal of the DCF Antenn I wrote the code:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setup("P8_10", GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    new_switch_state = GPIO.input("P8_11")
    print(new_switch_state)
```

Result is

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
.
.
.
.
```

So no signal is read. Could you help ? THX!

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet says: -

1. Earth
2. Operating voltage 1.2 … 1.5 V- (although the German DS appears to say 15 V)
3. DCF output
4. DCF output inverted

Outputs 3 and 4 of open collectors npn max. 30 V 1 mA

So it looks like you have powered it with too much voltage (unless you read the German DS) and you don't understand what an [open collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) is - it requires a pull-up resistor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added a pullup resistor of 10kOhm.

Comment: @BenJo did it work?

Comment: Nope :P unfortunately

Comment: Keep working at it then LOL